# Use shared variables in charts

Tags: crystal-reports

My Crystal Report has 5 groups:

- DirectoryID
- RID
- QID
- GroupID
- FormID
  I have few columns  QuestionType,IsMarkedasNA,OriginalScore,QuestionMaxScore,QuestionMinScore.

I have score calculation based on below formula at FormID Level.

```
SUM(OriginalScore) - SUM(QuestionMinScore) / SUM(QuestionMaxScore) - SUM(QuestionMinScore)
```

I need the Maximum, Minimum, Median, and Average of the scores for different formIDs at the GroupID level. Shared Variables calculate it accordingly. Subreport charts display these values.

One more Chart which at QID level needs to compare the Maximum scores of different GroupID levels. I can only get the last FormID Max(Value), but I need all the max(Value)s from all forms.

Comment: Can you elaborate some concrete example here?

Comment: I have added required information. Please let me know if you need further information